# What is the best way to create Cookie Session? (Code Cloning issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I'm not using any default ASP.NET MVC Authentication, so I create my own Authentication with a cookie & session to my project for my security. This code below is my function Login that the first time cookie and session generated.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    bool ValidEmail = db.Users.Any(u => u.Username == user.Username);

    if (!ValidEmail)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    string Password = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == user.Username).Select(u => u.Password).Single();
    user.Password = GenerateHashPassword(user.Password);

    if (Password != user.Password)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    string AuthID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["AuthID"] = AuthID;
    var Cookie = new HttpCookie("AuthID");
    Cookie.Values["AuthID"] = AuthID;
    Cookie.Values["Username"] = user.Username;
    Cookie.Values["LastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
    Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
}
```

Then it redirects to `ProjectController`. To every single functions in this controller, I make some if statement that If Cookies is not equal to Session by the same AuthID Values, then it redirects to the Home Page (before login). For example like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] == Session["AuthID"].ToString())
        {
             // main code here ... 
        }
        else
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] == Session["AuthID"].ToString())
        {
             // main code here ... 
        }
        else
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] == Session["AuthID"].ToString())
        {
             // main code here ... 
        }
        else
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] == Session["AuthID"].ToString())
        {
             // main code here ... 
        }
        else
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

...
```

This will prevent users who are not in a logged-in state can't access the link (i.e.  `localhost:60612/Project`  or  `localhost:60612/Project/Create` or  `localhost:60612/Project/Edit/3`  etc.) and will redirect to the Home Page.

The problem here is how to minimize the repeating `if statement` code in each function, remembering to some of the Software Quality Assurance Aspects:

> If there are some same exact codes, write them once in a new function then call it by another functions which needed (*Extract Method*). This will prevent the **Code Cloning** or **Code Duplicate** issues (Bad Smell) to your software project and enhance your Software Performance Quality

How do I supposed to minimize this code? Or are there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want to use **[FormAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** which works with default **[AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)** out of the box.

Since you implement your own logic, you want to override **AuthorizeAttribute**.

For example -

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private bool AuthorizeUser(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = false;

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext != null)
        {
            var context = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;

            if (context.Session["AuthID"] != null &&
                context.Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] ==
                context.Session["AuthID"].ToString())
            {
                isAuthorized = true;
            }
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        if (AuthorizeUser(filterContext))
            return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
public class MyController : Controller
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is typically done with authentication filters. Maybe just google it but here is a related article http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters

Answer (score 0):

Generic logic applied on many actions should usually be handled by action filters.
But for the authorization/authentication case, you really should use some proved and hardened and widely used solution, rather than implementing your own.

About the action filter, the basic general principle is to derive from `ActionFilterAttribute`, implements your custom generic logic in its `OnActionExecuting` method, and apply it to your actions. See [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/14/aspnetmvc-filters.aspx/) for more details on the general case.

For the authorization case, with such a custom logic as yours, you should implement `IAuthorizationFilter`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,
    Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YourAuthorizationFilterAttribute :
    FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext.Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] ==
            httpContext.Session["AuthID"].ToString())
            // Let the action get executed
            return;

        // Otherwise redirect
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(
            filterContext.Controller.Url("Index", "Home"));
    }
}
```

---

```
[YourAuthorizationFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // main code here
}
```

For avoiding decorating most of your actions with this attribute, you may set it on controller or set it as a global filter (best solution for not forgetting it on actions requiring authentication).

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new YourAuthorizationFilter());
        ...
```

But then, you will probably need a way to deactivate it for some actions such as the login one. It should be done using another action filter attribute (say `YourAllowAnonymousAttribute`), which presence would be tested by `YourActionFilterAttribute`, and if present, `YourAuthorizationFilter` would then be deactivated.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,
    Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YourAllowAnonymousAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // Nothing to implement.
}
```

---

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,
    Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YourAuthorizationFilterAttribute :
    FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(
                typeof(YourAllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit) ||
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
                typeof(YourAllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
            return;
        ...
```

---

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     ...
     [YourAllowAnonymous]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         ...
```

Deriving from `AuthorizeFilter` as in this [answer](/a/37038971/1178314) will not redirect you where you want "out of the box", you would have to configure Asp.Net forms authentication in web.config (that is why it mentions "FormAuthentication").

Another solution is to use a custom base controller and override its `OnActionExecuting` method, but the action filter should be preferred.

But I insist, implementing your own authorization scheme is usually an anti-pattern. Security is a hard matter, there is many traps with those kind of logic. Maybe this is not at all a concern for your application, but just in case:

- Depending on session leaves vulnerable to session thefts as session is cookie based too.
- Authentication cookie should be signed and this signature should be checked on each request for avoiding browser user to tinker with authentication cookie data such as the username.
- Cookie should be marked as `HttpOnly` for avoiding JavaScript to be able to access it.
- If served over HTTPS, it should be marked a `Secure` for avoiding it to be transmitted later on over unsecured HTTP.
- An expiration date should be embedded in its data (and be included in signature) for avoiding endless replay of it (the cookie expiration can be tinkered with by attackers).
- ...